# Multiline <p> and <label> fontsize changing depending on number of lines

Tags: html, css, asp.net

For some reason when having multiline paragraphs or labels the fontsize adjusts depending on how many lines they are, all i'm after is to have the font-size consistent regardless of the lines, the labels have exactly the same css styling and have identicial inheritance;

[This shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I83pY.jpg)

```
element.style {
}
@media (min-width: 320px)
.FAQAs {
    /* width: 95%; */
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-top: 3vw;
    padding-bottom: 3vw;
    padding-right: 3vw;
    float: left;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: grey;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    width: -moz-available;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    width: fill-available;
}
@media (min-width: 320px)
.FAQFontSize {
    /* font-size: 3.2vw; */
    font-size: 31.7px;
}
* {
    font-family: Verdana;
}
label[Attributes Style] {
}
user agent stylesheet
label {
    cursor: default;
}
@media (min-width: 320px)
.bodyFontSize {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

I've tried using different units for the font-size (em/px/pt etc), i've tried changing the inheritance, setting parents font-size, nothing seems to be working

https://jsfiddle.net/4prwzt36/

that's the JSfiddle, it's specific to mobile devices however so i'm not sure how to set that on jsfiddle, the desktop version is fine

Comment: make your example reproducible. add html

Comment: your code works well. the font is the same everywhere for different sizes of the browser window. Which browser do you see this error in?

Comment: All mobile browsers

Comment: try put to `head` tag - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I've had to readjust all my font sizes but that's worked! thanks for that, am i able to mark a comment as the answer or can you post it as an answer so i can mark it please

Comment: I am very glad that you managed to solve the problem. I gave you the answer. You can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `head` tag.